# Recalculate Normals flips faces direction?

Tags: normals

When I recalculate normals all the faces flip direction.

Why is this happening?

How can I avoid this and keep the faces facing the direction I want to, even if I recalculate again?

**Before Recalculating Normals**
[image: Before Recalculating Normals]

**After Recalculating Normals**
[image: After Recalculating Normals]

Comment: There are various reason why this happens, it could be caused by overlapping vertices or edges, scaling issues, export and import issues, none manifold faces ... etc.

Comment: I'm curious why you have so many densely packed edges in one area... looks like there may be a topology issue here that should be addressed first.

Comment: Try Shift Ctrl N (Recalculate Inside) instead of Ctrl N (Recalculate Outside). Blender determines what is inside and what is outside base on the mesh structure.